# как отфильтровать jsonb поле по нескольким ключам?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица `groups` c jsonb полем `targets`

Мой запрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT groups.* 
FROM groups 
WHERE groups.user_id = 1 AND (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(targets) as a 
    WHERE a->>'name' ~* 'gender|age'
  ) 
)
```

Который возвращает `groups` только с `gender`, только с `age`, и `gender` и `age` вместе

Как поправить запрос, чтобы он возвращал `groups` только с `gender` и `age` вместе

Само поле `targets` выглядит так:

```
[{"name"=>"gender", "value"=>"0"}, {"name"=>"age", "value"=>"1"}]
```

Comment: Ну самое простое - это 2 EXISTS. Только использовать лучше всё же не строковое сравнение, а чисто JSON-операторы (в данном случае - `jsonb ? text → boolean`).